# '$' is undefined

Tags: jquery

I get this error whether I put the jQuery $.ajax call in a  `$(document).ready(function() {` or not. This is on a ASP.NET MVC .cshtml file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/courses',
            success: function(data) {
                var list = $('#courses');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var course = data[i];
                    list.append('<li id="' + course.id + '">' + course.name + '</li>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you remembering to include jQuery first?

Comment: Is the jquery file referenced before the above script?

Comment: You are missing `<` in `script type="text/javascript">`.. I guess it is a copy paste mistake.

Comment: No I actually have the < in the code. Just didn't translate to here

Comment: Mario, its complicated. Its an ASP.NET MVC cshtml file but it loads a common layout (_layout.cshtml) file which references jquery at the bottom

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you reference JQuery first. Something along the lines of (using MS CDN):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/courses',
            success: function(data) {
                var list = $('#courses');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var course = data[i];
                    list.append('<li id="' + course.id + '">' + course.name + '</li>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: , its complicated. Its an ASP.NET MVC cshtml file but it loads a common layout (_layout.cshtml) file which references jquery at the bottom

Comment: The point being, though, when the final web page is built, in the DOM, does the script tag for referencing jquery appear before your script tag with the ajax call. I use MVC2 regularly, and I've solved this problem with Master pages to my views, the master page having the jquery include at the top.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks! Marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

On a server on the local network with IE 11, it can also be a compatibility view issue.

See my answer to this question for more details: ['$' is undefined. How to use jQuery 2.0.1 in empty ASP.NET MVC 4 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862643/is-undefined-how-to-use-jquery-2-0-1-in-empty-asp-net-mvc-4-project/24455736#24455736)